# Area of a square on top of a quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, area

> In quadrilateral $ABCD, \angle ABC + \angle DCB = 90^\circ$ and $ADEF$ is a square constructed on side $AD$ in the exterior of the quadrilateral $ABCD.$ If $BC = 10 $ cm, $AC = 9$ cm and $BD = 8$ cm, then the area of the square $ADEF$ lies between
>
> (a) $70$ and $80$
>
> (b) $60$ and $70$
>
> (c) $50$ and $60$
>
> (d) $40$ and $50$

I drew a rough sketch using Geogebra. Looks like the area of square should be between $40$ and $50.$

But I am not able to come with a proof. Any hints on how to proceed
[image]

Comment: You visibly accept non-convex quadrilaterals but do you forbid self intersecting quadrilaterals ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend $\small CD$ to meet $\small AB$ at $\small E$.

[image: img]

Since $\small \measuredangle B+\measuredangle C=90^\circ$, we can see $\small \angle BEC=90^\circ.$

Now from Pythagorean theorem,

$\small BC^2=EB^2+EC^2\tag1$

$\small AD^2=EA^2+ED^2\tag2$

Adding both,

$\small \begin{align} BC^2+AD^2&=(EB^2+ED^2)+(EC^2+EA^2)\\ &=BD^2+AC^2\end{align}$

Now substituting,

$\small 10^2+AD^2=8^2+9^2\implies AD^2=\dots$

And $\small AD^2$ means ...

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Hint: As can be seen in figure AD=A'D', where A and A' are two positions. This is what you have to show, i. e AD is constant in all positions. Hence the area of square on AD is about $6.7^2\approx 45$, that is option (d) is correct.